# Cassandra: nodetool status gives way too different data sizes after inserting almost same amount of data 2 independent times

Tags: database, cassandra

I inserted almost the same amount of data in a table in my 16-node cassandra ring and the difference in size is way too big!

The first time according to `nodetool status` there was around 5Gb on each node and the table was:

```
CREATE TABLE t1(
id varchar,
c2 text,
c3 float,
c4 float,
c5 float,
c6 text,
c7 text,
c8 text,
PRIMARY KEY ((id),c2, c3, c4, c5, c6, c7, c8)
);
```

For the 2nd time I run a `truncate t1` then `drop table t1` and then a `nodetool -h localhost -p 7199 clearsnapshot --all` on every node. I created the new table with on more column(varchar) as below (which is a converted UUID to String) and I inserted the data the same way.

```
CREATE TABLE t1(
id varchar,
extraid varchar,
c2 text,
c3 float,
c4 float,
c5 float,
c6 text,
c7 text,
c8 text,
PRIMARY KEY ((id),extraid)
);
```

The number of rows was the same in both times(~1.1 billion rows). However, now the amount is approximately 17Gb per node. There are no pending flushes and I also run a full repair.

Any idea why that happened?
Could it be that some compaction did not take place?

Comment: Did you make a note of the compression ratio reported for the tables on each node?

Comment: That is a valid point for which I run the 2 cases again. For the 1st case I had ~0.25 in all the nodes and for the 2nd ~0.65 in all the nodes. Also, the SSTable Count in both cases varies from 6 to 10 in all the nodes. (The ratio of the 1st case also justifies why reads in that case are faster as there is less decompression happening). But why such a huge difference in the ratio? And if I have only ~5Gb/node on the 1st case, isn't that expected to have a bigger Compression Ratio comparing to the ~17Gb in the 2nd case??

Comment: With the clustering order being different, but the compression is no doubt set to the default chunk size of 64kb, different data is being grouped together for compression, which will materially alter the effectiveness of it. Various performance factors then occur as a result. It doesn't entirely explain the difference though since you can divide the totals by the ratio to get back to the uncompressed size. (5gb / 0.25) 20gb vs (17gb / 0.65) 26GB, with the extra field, that perhaps adds up - its not possible for me to tell.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! The 17Gb per node is an approximate average, it varies from 15 to 25(very few). I am mostly interested to improve my read performance. The Ratio of the 1st case is way better than the 2nd one! But then, does this mean that the more columns we have as clustering columns in the primary key, the better read performance we will have? So what if we have all columns in the primary key? (I tried also with 4 columns in total in the primary key and got ~0.46 Compress Ratio, indicating that the more columns I add the better Ratio I get..)